# How can I make a ListView fit between a Button and ImageView vertically

Tags: android

I am trying to create a ListView which fits between a Button and an ImageView.
I have a RelativeLayout which has a Button at the top and an ImageView at the bottom.
I want a ListView between them. This is what I have done.

I see my listView under the Button, but it is overlapping with the ImageView at the bottom.
So how can I make it so that the ListView above the ImageView?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/control_panel"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/mywidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_shutter" />

        <ListView android:id="@+id/image_list"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"/>

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="@dimen/mywidth"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing the values of your `@dimen` variables.

Comment: Try calculating the distance between the bottom of your Button and the top of your ImageView, then set this as the ListView's height at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/control_panel"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/mywidth"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_shutter" />

        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="@dimen/mywidth"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/image_list"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you set on the RelativeLayout?  If not, you could use a LinearLayout with weighting.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control_panel"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/mywidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
         />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/image_list"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:layout_weight="6"/>

    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image"
       android:layout_width="@dimen/mywidth"
       android:layout_height="0px"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: Why use android:layout_weight="6" in ListView? what is the meaning of the value 6? And does layout_above, layout_below still works in LinearLayout?

Comment: Oops, I meant to remove layout_above and layout_below.  I modified the code accordingly.  The layout_weight="6" is essentially a ratio of what portion of the parent view should be filled by that element.  With a weight of 1 for the button and image the total would be 8, making the list view take up 6/8 of the parent LinearLayout.  The weights can then be adjusted to suit your needs.